# Восстановить панель инструментов

Tags: android-studio

Случайно закрыл панель Project слева в Android Studio.

Может кто знает, как ее восстановить?
Дефолт настройка ничего не дает.

Comment: пробовали нажать Alt + 1 ?

Comment: Да, уже заработала ))))  спасибо!!!